# How to make buttons change with animation

Tags: android, view, scrollview, android-animation

i should to do like at the picture.[image: this]Buttons have to change with animations. It must be like circle horizontal scroll view.When i press button "3" - "1" - moved to position "2", "2" moved with animation to position "3". Please give me some ideas, how can i perform it?

Comment: Have you tried something? post your code

Comment: id don't know how to make it, thats why i post question there. I try to make 3 buttons, and i make change text on t affter button pressed, but i don't know how to make it with animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

**STEP 1:**

Create 4 `Button's` **dummy_btn,btn_1,btn_2,btn_3** in xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dummy_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**STEP 2:**

Declear the Button's in Global variables like below

```
Button btn_1,btn_2,btn_3,dummy_btn;
```

Initialize `Button's` like below

```
btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
btn_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
dummy_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_btn);
```

**STEP 3:**

**btn_1** `ClickListener` like below

```
 btn_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Get all currently displaying text of Button
            final String btn_1_string = btn_1.getText().toString().trim();
            final String btn_2_string = btn_2.getText().toString().trim();
            final String btn_3_string = btn_3.getText().toString().trim();

            // First Button Left to Right Animation
            TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 200f, 0f, 0f); 
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            btn_1.startAnimation(anim);

            // Second Button Left to Right Animation
            anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 200f, 0f, 0f); 
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            btn_2.startAnimation(anim);

            // Third Button Left to Right Animation
            anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 200f, 0f, 0f); 
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            btn_3.startAnimation(anim);

            btn_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            dummy_btn.setText(btn_3.getText().toString().trim());

            // Dummy Button Left to Right Animation for like marquee animation
            dummy_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim = new TranslateAnimation(-200f, 0f, 0f, 0f); 
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            dummy_btn.startAnimation(anim);

            // After 2000 Millis displaying text
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn_2.setText(btn_1_string);
                    btn_3.setText(btn_2_string);
                    btn_1.setText(btn_3_string);
                    btn_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dummy_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);                     
                }

            }, 2000);

        }

     });
```

and the remaining two `Button ClickListener`

```
     btn_2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            btn_1.performClick();
        }

     });

     btn_3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                btn_1.performClick();
            }

    });
```

Comment: it works, but isn't good. when i press button one - buttons change their size(become smaller) and there is a lot of free space, it like as i have 5 buttons and 1 is invisible

Comment: @KostyaKhuta That size reduce because if dummy_btn visible's that time size will reduce.

Comment: I want to have smooth animation